# Which compute instance property pertains to "Block project-wide SSH keys"?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created a GCE VM (i.e. a `compute.v1.instance`) using Cloud Deployment Manager (I've downloaded Deployment.zip from https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/scientiamobile-public/wurfl-microservice-basic?project=msm-groupdata-sharedresources and deployed that using `gcloud deployment-manager deployments create`).

After deploying the VM I notice that the "Block project-wide SSH keys" property is not checked
[image: project wide ssh keys screenshot]

I would like to change this (its company policy to have this box checked) in my deployment package which would involve changing a property however I can't figure out which property to change. I've looked through https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances which is the API reference for `compute.v1.instance` but it isn't obvious to me which property in there would toggle this "Block project-wide SSH keys" option.

Please can someone tell me what I need to change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify to block project-wide SSH keys in Cloud Deployment Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312988/how-can-i-specify-to-block-project-wide-ssh-keys-in-cloud-deployment-manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Its not a property, its metadata. [ENSURE 'BLOCK PROJECT-WIDE SSH KEYS' ENABLED FOR VM INSTANCES](https://gsl.dome9.com/D9.GCP.CRY.02.html) was useful.

I've provided an example of using Cloud Deployment Manager to set "Block project-wide SSH keys" at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328479/201657

Comment: Please update your answer to show an example using Deployment Manager. Knowing that there is a setting and being able to deploy a solution are two different things.

Comment: Updated with a link to where I've shared that info. thanks.